# Postfix doesn't send domain mail to mx

Tags: postfix, mx-record

I'm trying to get postfix to forward email to my domain which is hosted by gmail. As I don't have any users on my server nor do I want to.

Here's how I have things set up. Let's say you and I have a domain called `mcdonalds.com`.

The registrar has mcdonalds.com MX records pointing to gmail. Everything works for like a year.

Now we set up a server to host a website.

Then we create a mail account called `sales@mcdonalds.com` and send mail locally from the server using roundcube.

This works.

We can send mail to `cnn.com`, to `serverfault.com` or to any/everyone.

BUT we cannot send mail to our own domain, `mcdonalds.com`.

So I cannot email to `info@mcdonalds.com`, to `bob@mcdonalds.com` or to `support@mcdonalds.com`.

It gives the following error:

`SMTP Error (450): Failed to add recipient "bob@mcdonalds.com" (4.1.1 <bob@mcdonalds.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table).`

I'm guessing because it is looking at the local server to find the mailbox, which doesn't exist.

So how to I tell the server for any mail going to `mcdonalds.com` for `bob@mcdonalds.com` to send to my external mail server, and *not* to lookup on the local www box we set up with zpanel?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transport` for that (http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html).

put in `/etc/postfix/transport`

```
mcdonalds.com   :aspmx.l.google.com
```

Don't forget to run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` after that.

Comment: tried that.. but no luck.  Added the line to transport and then did the postmap..

Comment: error was

Mar 28 09:24:51 server postfix/pickup[10079]: DC00615A20D7: uid=0 from=<sender@mcdonalds.com>
Mar 28 09:24:51 server postfix/cleanup[10094]: DC00615A20D7: message-id=<20130328142451.DC00615A20D7@www.mcdonalds.com>
Mar 28 09:24:51 server postfix/qmgr[10080]: DC00615A20D7: from=<sender@mcdonalds.com>, size=322, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 28 09:24:52 server postfix/pipe[10085]: DC00615A20D7: to=<recipient@mcdonalds.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.18, delays=0.12/0/0/0.07, dsn=4.1.1, status=SOFTBOUNCE (user unknown)

Comment: You could leave local_recipient_maps empty in main.cf but this would not be a good idea because it will forward to gmail all emails for your domain, even if recipients does not exist. If this server is is exposed in internet it could be a big problem. You could list all existing recipients in a file and use this file in local_recipient_maps (something like local_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/usernames). http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html

Comment: You could also change mydomain in main.cf to something like server.mcdonalds.com. This way the server will not think that mails for @mcdonalds.com are for itself and it will forward them to MX.

Comment: I did try that too beforehand! (changing the mydomain to xzy.com I made up.. and no luck :(  )

The local recipent maps is already blank. (the email addresses are fixed.. 4 addresses .  But I don't want to staticly assign addresses just in case I add more people.. but the usernames wouldn't work cuz I have no local mailboxes... right?

Comment: I'll paste the main.cf:
# postfix config file
# uncomment for debugging if needed
soft_bounce=yes
# postfix main
mail_owner = postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
delay_warning_time = 4
# postfix paths
html_directory = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES

Comment: ew: that didn't work.   # network settings
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
# mydomain = mcdonalds.com
myhostname = www.mcdonalds.com
mynetworks = all
mydestination =
# relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
relayhost =

Comment: set mydestination=$myhostname

Comment: I have tried that..

Comment: I'm at the stage now that I think it's relaying out, but now get relay not allow error: Recipient address rejected: aspmx.l.google.com

Comment: Mar 31 18:03 server postfix/smtpd[9640]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: 450 4.1.1 <person@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: aspmx.l.google.com; from=<sender123@mydomain.com> to=<person@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost.localdomain>
Mar 31 18:03:28 server sendmail[9638]: r2VN3RGI009638: to=person@mydomain.com, ctladdr=sender123@mydomain.com (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30004, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.1.1, stat=Deferred: 450 4.1.1 <person@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: aspmx.l.google.com

Comment: I also get: Relay access denied when sending to another domain... grrrr

Comment: Please paste your main.cf somewhere (for example http://pastebin.com/) and post the link, it is hard to read it from comment.

Comment: thanks for now. We found a work around.. we updated Drupal to use google's SMTP... thanks for your help and attention.

Comment: For it to work you must not have the mcdonalds.com domain in your `mydestination` option (just server.mcdonalds.com or something). create a transport like Laurentiu posted. But postfix won't use it automatically, you have to put `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` in your `main.cf`. Also, create a file `/etc/postfix/relay_domains`, put `mcdonalds.com  ok` in it, hash it with `postmap /etc/postfix/relay_domains`, and put `relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_domains` in your `main.cf`, restart postfix. That should do it.